Inconsistent ruby case statement behavior with trailing commas and assignments
Stumbled into a weird error, and I'm curious if anyone can explain this inconsistency or if I should send this to the ruby team as a proper bug. I'm currently using ruby 3.2.2.
Take this script as a template:
def my_method
  return ["test1", "test2"]
end

def run_it
  ...
end

run_it

If run_it looks like this:
  case "123"
  when "123", x, y = my_method
    puts y.inspect
  end

Output will be 'nil'. Would expect undefined method or variable x.
If run_it looks like this:
  case "123"
  when "123", x, y = my_method
    puts x.inspect
    puts y.inspect
  end

I get:
undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object (NameError)

    puts x.inspect
         ^
    from script.rb:13:in `<main>'

After further testing, it appears this behavior is at least partially because 'when' statements stop evaluating once it finds a matched item. So if '"123"' and 'x' were to trade places, you would see undefined method/variable 'x'. The even stranger part is that y is defined as nil while x is left undefined (y being defined makes sense, but why isn't it getting the value from my_method?).
I still can't repeat the case we hit in a standalone form, however this is the sanitized version of our code (bug still present). Maybe you can spot something I missed:
    when ConstantReference1,
      ConstantReference2,
      recipient, cc_recipients = collect_recipients(*arbitrary_args)
      send_mail(
        arbitrary_arg1,
        arbitrary_arg2,
        recipient,
        {
          something: arbitrary_arg3,
          cc_recipients: cc_recipients
        },
        arbitrary_arg4,
        attachments: attach(arbitrary_arg5)
      ).deliver

In this code example, recipient came up nil instead of undefined. So despite being able to replicate some of it in the smaller example, this one seems to contradict my own testing. recipient and cc_recipients are the only pieces meant to be defined in the snippet. The remainder are defined elsewhere in the file/project.
P.S. If anyone is curious about how we got here, a code update had an errant comma on the end of a 'when' statement that was followed by a variable assignment which lead to some obscure test failures. After we saw the trailing comma and verified its removal resolved the issues, we started digging into why this didn't cause a larger failure or more obvious error (only the tests on that 'when' failed, but I would have expected any evaluation of the case statement to fail with undefined variable).
Can anyone explain these behaviors?

Case expressions with multiple conditions are evaluated in order using == so x == "123" is never reached. y = my_method on the other hand is still evaluated at parsing time as a local variable assignment (although my_method is never called). I cannot describe your experience regarding your recipient situation.

"recipient came up nil instead of undefined" – most likely, recipient was defined somewhere else. Maybe you have a recipient = ... assignment in another when block before. Note that a "[...] local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs" (from Assignment – Local Variables and Methods).

To add on to @Stefan's comment were ConstantReference1, ConstantReference2, recipient, cc_recipients = collect_recipients(*arbitrary_args) to be wrapped in parens e.g. (ConstantReference1, ConstantReference2, recipient, cc_recipients = collect_recipients(*arbitrary_args)) then ruby will view this as multiple assignment resulting in the possibility of recipient being nil; however, you would also receive warnings for already initialized constants.

From the examples you gave, it seems like you expect when "123", x, y = my_method to be read by Ruby like this
when "123", (x, y = my_method)

but Ruby reads it like this
when "123", x, (y = my_method)

When "123" matches, then the rest of the line is parsed but not evaluated anymore. Therefore, Ruby knows that a variable y exists even if it is not set. But x is never set and therefore returns a undefined local variable or method error.

This seems to be it. The only part I don't understand is why recipient didn't come up undefined in the actual code. It's working now though, and I don't really have time to dig into it. Thanks for taking the time to answer!
